# HTML generated for RichTextArea: what is #document?

Tags: javascript, html, gwt, dom

I can see in Chrome Develoer Tools that html generated for GWT's `RichTextArea` widget is something like this:

```
<iframe class="GCJ2VDKDEI" style="height: 40px; ">
  #document
    <html>
      <head></head>
      <body>entered text</body>
    </html>
</iframe>
```

Could somebody desribe how it works? How is it possible that page embedded in `<iframe>` is editable for user (looks and behaves like text area)?

I would especially like to know what is that strange `#document` thing. It's first time I see something like this and Google gives me no answers :(.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the `Document` node of the document inside the iframe. [All `Document` nodes have a `nodeName` property of "#document"](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#dom-node-nodename), which you can see by examining `document.nodeName`. Chrome's developer tools are probably handling the iframe by adding an expansion of the iframe's `contentDocument` property as a child of the iframe expansion.

As to the document being editable, it's very common for WYSIWYG editors to use an iframe for the editable content. All current browsers allow built-in editing functionality on any element via the [`contenteditable`](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/editing.html#contenteditable) attribute, and also at a document level via the `document.designMode` property.

Comment: Could you please define what "expansion" means? Probably this is what I need to fully understand first part of your answer. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @PiotrSobczyk: It's probably the wrong term. What I mean by "expansion" is the way a DOM node and all its children are displayed in the Elements tab in Chrome's developer tools. When it encounters an iframe, it displays the element in the same way as any other element but also displays the document within the iframe as though it was a child node of the iframe element.